# How to send Images over TCP connection in Swift4

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, tcp, swift4

I am developing mac OS application in that i want to send the images in every 5 seconds to another mac . i am running Node.js TCP server at backend side , and connecting both of them as TCP Client .

I am  trying to send Base64 Encode String to server  and server is pushing data to clients .

**Receiving code :**

```
   extension SocketCreator: StreamDelegate {
        func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
            switch eventCode {
            case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
                print("new message received")
                //readAvailableBytes(stream: aStream as! InputStream)
            case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
                disconnectFromHost()
            case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
                print("error occurred  : \(aStream.streamError.debugDescription)")
            case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
                print("has space available")
            default:
                print("some other event...")
                break
            }
        }

        private func readAvailableBytes(stream: InputStream) {
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxReadLength)

            while (stream != NSNull.init())&&stream.hasBytesAvailable {
                let numberOfBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)

                if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
                    if let _ = inputStream.streamError {
                        break
                    }
                }

                let reciviedMsg = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer,
                                         length: numberOfBytesRead,
                                         encoding: .ascii,
                                         freeWhenDone: true)

                delegate?.scoktDidRecivceNewMessagew(message: reciviedMsg ?? "-NA-")


            }
        }
}
```

When i am receiving base64 string in second computer , i and loosing some on bits and base64 is not decodable . what could be the possible reason for this.

if am doing wrong to send data in base64 encode string , what is the best practice to Images over TCP without loosing data .

This is how i am collecting fragments:

```
 func scoktDidRecivceNewMessage(message: String) {
       // print("Recived Command @ cient : \(message)")
        if message.contains("data:image/png;base64,") {
            hasStartedReadingImage = true
            base64ImageFrame = message
        }

        if hasStartedReadingImage {
            if message.contains("**end")
            {
                hasStartedReadingImage = false
                base64ImageFrame.append(message)
                var base64 = base64ImageFrame.replacingOccurrences(of: "data:image/jpeg;base64,", with: "")
                base64 = base64.replacingOccurrences(of: "**end", with: "")

                let nsImage = base64.base64Convert()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imgStremingView.image = nsImage
                }


            }else
            {
               base64ImageFrame.append(message)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you delimiting each image?  The number of bytes arriving for each callback can vary. You need to add some framing to your messages so that you know when you have received a completed image and you can start decoding it. You don't need to base64 encode the image data. A tcp socket will send 8 bit data

Comment: I am adding `data/image:` at beginning  and at the end adding `**end` i am able to get those two but base64 string is distroyed somewhere

Comment: You should show the code where you reassemble the fragments; ie your delegate method. And there is no need for base64 encoding. Add an appropriate header that has the number of bytes and then you can send 8 bit data in the stream

Comment: The problem is with your reassembly code. Your use of contains means that a packet that arrives containing "xxxxx**enddata:image/png;base64,yyyyyy" would be considered the start of a new image, plus the end of that image and you have lost the end of the previous image too. You need to go through each byte, looking for the start and the end.  I would also suggest a finite state machine to keep track of what you are expecting

Comment: Question updated sir ,  and also  how can i send image data to another pc if i don't  want to use Base64 .

Comment: As I said, you can just send the raw bytes. A TCP stream doesn't care what you put into it